# Background-image not 100%

Tags: html, css

I want to create something like that: [Page](http://www.lol-coaching.eu/)

With some help the result is at the momemnt that: [MyPage](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/neuer%20Versuch/). I dont want that the background-image is 100%. I want only the real high. How can change that? 
I tried alot, but it wont work :/

Here is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <!-- Open Sans -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
             <h1></h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Demo

```css
* {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8226/8557105873_a82c51f03f_z.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
nav {
  background: url("images/line-header.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom #4A525A;
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav > ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul > li {
  margin-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  color: #697683;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}
nav ul li > a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
.content {
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!-- Open Sans -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `margin-top` on `.content` to `100%` instead of 500px

```
.content{
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 500px; <---- change to 100%
  background-color: orange;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpbqdczj/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking for, but if your *high* means *height*, maybe you should use `contain` instead of `cover` for the `background-size`.

```
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-o-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! My problem is, that the background-image is at the moment streched. height = 100% and width too. I dont want that the height is 100%.

Comment: I want something like that on the example page. The picture and if someone scolls the white div container move over the picture

Answer (score 0):

Well the lol-coaching page you linked is not scaling at all, also they have [cropped their image](http://cdn1.editmysite.com/uploads/3/8/9/4/38945355/background-images/748028443.png) to show only what they need.

[image: lol-coaching header]

They also did not attach the background to the body, it put it in a separate header div.

```
 .wsite-background {
      background-image: url('//cdn1.editmysite.com/uploads/3/8/9/4/38945355/background-images/748028443.png') !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      background-position: 50% 0 !important;
      background-size: auto !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
      background: inherit;
 }
```

### **EDIT:**

But if you just want to have your image start higher up, take advantage of the background-position and edit the second variable. **[[jsFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/sjx50h9q/)** with your code.

```
background-position: 0 50% !important;
```

Comment: Yes i want to put the image in a own div container and not in the background. But i had some help from this forum and they wrote me to put it in the background. Maybe you can help me with this? - Thanks for the answer!